# TypeError: Cannot read property 'stringify' of undefined when using crypto.js inside node

Tags: javascript

**Problem is at /add cryptojs works fine but at /edit it gives the error cannot read property **

```
router.post("/add",(req,res)=>{
    let pass = req.body.password
    Promise.resolve(Users.create(fname,lname,email,cryptojs.AES.encrypt(pass,"password_key"),type)).then(function(value){
        res.render("employees.hbs",{
            error:3
        })
    }) 
})

router.post("/edit",(req,res)=>{
    let pass = req.body.password

    Promise.resolve(Users.edit(id,fname,lname,email,cryptojs.AES.encrypt(pass,"password_key"),type)).then(function(value){
        res.render("employees.hbs",{
            error:6
        })
    }) 
})
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?